# virt-manager can't open the display

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt

My `virt-manager` was working just fine and all of a sudden stopped working, throwing in error: `RuntimeError: could not open display`

```
root@rakcal ~]# echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0

[root@rakcal ~]# virt-manager 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-manager.py", line 383, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-manager.py", line 286, in main
    raise gtk_error
RuntimeError: could not open display
```

Has anyone seen this before? the same thing happen to "virt-viewer" as well:

```
[root@rakcal ~]# virt-viewer winxp1
Cannot open display: 
Run 'virt-viewer --help' to see a full list of available command line options
```

Does anyone know what might be the problem or if I'm missing anything? Reinstalling "virt-manager" didn't bring any good. Any help would be appreciated. Cheers!!

Comment: Did you run this in a remote ssh shell, without X forwarding? does the server have X installed?

Comment: I certainly didn't do it without X forwarding; otherwise `echo $DISPLAY` wouldn't return anything. There is no need to install full X on the server, only `xauth` (with associated dependencies installed) will work just fine. In fact, it worked just fine for for 4/5 days until yesterday morning; since then it started giving trouble. Cheers!!

Comment: then I'd start looking at the logs for libvirt (libvirt.log and libvirtd.log) and track back the changes recently made to the system

Comment: Do *any* X programs work?  Absent a full X install, maybe you can install something like `xeyes` or `xdpyinfo`.  The idea here is to figure out if this is a problem with `virt-viewer` or with the underlying X forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

If you use ssh X forwarding try:

```
ssh -Y user@remotehost virt-manager
```

From SSH manpage:

> -Y      Enables trusted X11 forwarding.  Trusted X11 forwardings are not subjected to the X11 SECURITY extension controls.